# how to do setup for clickhouse keeper

Tags: clickhouse

I am trying to use clickhouse keeper as per the given article https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-setup-and-maintenance/altinity-kb-zookeeper/clickhouse-keeper/

When I replace the hostname1 and hostname2 with my remote server ips, I'm getting error as->

1. RaftInstance: total 1 nodes (including this node) responded for pre-vote (term 0, live 0, dead 1), at least 2 nodes should respond
2. RaftInstance: peer (2) response error: failed to connect to peer 2, x.x.x.x:9444
3. RaftInstance: Election timeout, initiate leader election

Able to complete configuration with https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/guides/sre/clickhouse-keeper
But whenever running a query on cluster getting error

```
DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. 
DB::Exception: Watching task /clickhouse/task_queue/ddl/query-0000000003 
is executing longer than distributed_ddl_task_timeout (=180) seconds. 
There are 2 unfinished hosts (0 of them are currently active), 
they are going to execute the query in background. (TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED)
```

After running

```
FROM system.clusters
```

is_local for nodes is 0

Comment: did you run
`netstat -nltp | grep 9444`
to check clickhouse-keeper listen 9444 port?

Comment: @Slach Have tried it, not getting any response

Comment: try `netstat -nltp | grep clickhouse`, or  `netstat -nlp | grep 9444`, are you sure you run clickhouse-server with embedded keeper or standalone clickhouse-keeper?

run `ps auxf | grep clickhouse` on target node

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue with the port configuration. This GitHub issue should answer this question: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/36750